# Do we need to upload app first then to add add's in it

Tags: android, google-play, startapp

I am using `startapp` as for my app add's intergration , when i make my account here and want to download the SDK (Please also help out in case which SDK to download because its my first experience) I got the following

[image]

but as i didnt upload my application yet , which package name i need to enter , or do i need to upload my app first and then add add's in it and integrate it with SDK of startapp

Comment: No don't have to upload the app to the store. You need to enter your package name from the manifest file. The string `com.example.myapp`

Comment: To add to @LordRaydenMK make sure you don't change it after you set it, so make sure you don't 1) Want to change it later and 2) lose your signing keystore. I had #2 hit and it was a nightmare to fix.

Comment: Thank you @Mgamerz Don't lose my signing store ? can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: @AHFwhen you export an APK for upload to the Play Store you have to sign it with a keystore. All future updates for the app must have the same package name and have to be signed with the same keystore. More info http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html